# gsutil authentication code failure

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I need to download files from GCS to local machine. I tried gsutil config and download in my machine. In my win 8 64 bit, all worked fine. However when I try to setup the same in another dedicated machine which is win vista 23 bit, entering authentication code just shows Failure.
Python gsutil.py config -b pops up the browser with request url, I got the authentication code in browser...pasting that gives Failure.

I am new to Python and could not trace back the problem. Does gsutil have any limitation on number of machines we can configure for same login/project?

Appreciate any help in debugging this.

Also, is it possible to move GCS data into Google SQL Cloud. I am assuming running a script on Google App engine that reads from GCS, parse the data and insert to Google SQL cloud is possible. Are their any documentations/tools to do this?

Thanks
Dhurka

Comment: Hi - can you please send us the output of running python gsutil.py -D config -b? Please make sure to strip out the Authorization: header before sending it. If you'd prefer not to post on the public forum you can email it to gs-team@google.com. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeSchwartz Got clue based on debug logs. Connection to accounts.google.com was failing. The production system was behind proxy. Configured proxy in boto and it all worked! .boto file wasn't getting created because of the failure. Copied from another PC and configured proxy to it and then it created a new .boto file. Hurray!!it worked. thanks for the hint.